# Print/Export GUI interface at current state Ruby Shoes

Tags: ruby, shoes

Given the simple GUI posted down below, how can I create and save a screenshot of what the results of the code is? I don't care if I need to print it, export it to pdf, or save as a picture but I don't want to ask the user to screenshot or snip the page.

```
Shoes.app do

# Post and location of logo
  @moveme =  image 'C:\Users\warnerl\Documents\RubyFiles\TK_Dashboard_Logo.jpg', :width => 200
  @moveme.move(400,0)

# Gets users first and last name and saves them as variables
  @UserFirstName = ask("Please input your first name.")
  @UserLastName = ask("Please input your last name.")

# Create Certificate
  stack{
    para 'You got 100%'

     para "#{@UserFirstName} #{@UserLastName}"
     para 'Congratulations you passed!'

}
end
```

Comment: It is unclear what you want to accomplish. Where is your code? If it is about saving a file, you dont need Shoes. You can use Ruby to do that for you.

Comment: I tried to clarify more in the main question. I didn't think my code was really applicable to the question as i'm just trying to find a method, but if you think it would help I can post it. I have only been using ruby for 2 weeks so it is pretty rough i'm sure.

Comment: Honestly it is still not clear what is your issue? Is your code running or is there a block where your code behaves differently or you need help to understand how to do a very specific task? What is it? You can paste entire code but you would need to help a reader correctly identify snippets where you think should be the problem.

Comment: There are multiple issues how you have structured your code but I need to know what is your specific issue with what you want to accomplish.

Comment: I want a screenshot of the gui at the snippet of code under Fin/Certificate. The code works well enough, I don't have any unexpected behavior right now.

Comment: One way to do what you want is to track progress of what your users are doing. Keep writing them in a file. When they reach your expected state, you can trigger to generate a template pdf stored in your GUI and fill in whatever extra you need. And output that. This is not at all trivial. Many ruby gems are available to generate PDF.